# Proof that a series diverges

Tags: divergent-series

How could I show that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
Diverges without the use of  comparison test which I am able to show. Any hints would be great thanks.

Comment: Thanks Parcly 

Comment: What’s wrong with the comparison test?

Comment: I meant without using comparison test , added “limit” by accident

Comment: You could use the integral test!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:With the integral test, we have that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
are equiconvergent.

Comment: I have never read the word *equiconvergent* but I agree with your answer!

Comment: @manooooh I think it's not a common thing, but I saw it in an analysis note and I started to like it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the integral test:$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\log\left(M+\sqrt{1+M^2}\right)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the comparison test, compute $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{-2}}=1$$

Hence, by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), the series agrees with $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n}$$ which diverges.

Comment: *without the use of comparison test which I am able to show*

Comment: "comparison test" is different from "limit comparison test".